# What traits should simple enums in Rust derive?

Tags: enums, rust, traits

I have a lot of enums like this, they have only tags -- without any constructor parameters:

```rust
pub enum VarRec {
    Variant,
    Record,
}
```

I'm currently deriving them with these traits:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone, Ord, PartialOrd, Hash)]
```

I wish they can have the maximum number of traits implemented, as the enum is really simple and I don't want them to lose any power by missing a trait implementation. Anything else to add to the derive list?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. There's no set of traits that "all" types should implement; it depends on the type. `Eq` and `Ord` may not be appropriate for an enum with an `Unknown` variant, for instance. There *is* harm in deriving too much, because adding a trait implementation is a backwards-compatible change, but removing one is not. My recommendation is to `#[derive(Debug)]` on every externally visible type, and decide the rest on a case by case basis. Programming is an exercise in thinking, not just typing; this is something you need to *think* about.

Comment: What do you need `Ord` and `PartialOrd` for? Does it even make sense to order the variants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good summary can be found at the [Rust API Guidelines](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html). You've got most of the common traits they recommend, but you may also want to add `Display` and possibly `Default` if there's one variant you think of as more basic. The [`derive_more` crate](https://jeltef.github.io/derive_more/derive_more/) can help smooth the process of implementing `Display`.

There are lots more recommendations there, so you should take a look and see if any apply to your specific situation.